# react native DDP connection for Android

Tags: android, react-native, ddp

I would like to hook up my react native Android app to a Meteor backend with the ddp-client npm package. This works great with the iOS app but how do I configure it to work with react native Android? I have the latest RN installed and the ddp-client installed, but it throws an error when I call the `connect()` function. Here is my code in index.android.js :

```
let ddpclient = new DDPClient({
url: 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket'
});

console.log('DDP', ddpclient);
ddpclient.connect((error, wasReconnect) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('DDP connection error!');
    return;
  }
  if (wasReconnect) {
    console.log('Reestablishment of a connection');
  }
  console.log('Connected!');
});
ddpclient.subscribe('messages', [], ()=> {
  console.log('messages complete:');
  console.log(ddpclient.collections.messages);
});

ddpclient.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('ddp message: ' + msg);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use ip address 'ws://192.168:3000/websocket' instead of 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket'

Answer (score 1):

So this [repo](https://github.com/spencercarli/meteor-todos-react-native-2) has an excellent solution to this problem, and it works with both iOS and Android, in my experience.

<strike>So I found a sort of solution, though I am absolutely sure it can be optimized. This way I was able to subscribe to 3 separate Meteor collections on the React Native Android app. Here it goes:</strike>

Comment: it is a bit idiosyncratic, but other techniques that might seem obvious were only allowing me to pick up one subscription